# Use a wired gamepad on Android 4.0.4 via laptop?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, keyboard, game-controllers

I have a USB-based gamepad that I use on my laptop. I want to use the same controller on my Android phone. The problem is I don't have a USB-to-MicroUSB cable so I can't directly connect it to the phone. However, I discovered [Wifi Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volosyukivan&hl=en). It works neatly if I use my laptop keyboard but I can't find any documentation about the usage of it's "Game Mode". I am trying to get Wifi Keyboard to use my gamepad on an emulator I have on the Android. If I try to set an input key on the emulator and I use my laptop keyboard, it gets detected and set. However, if I use my gamepad, nothing happens.

How do I execute the setup I have in mind?

Comment: Another option is to get a USB OTG cable. This is essentially just a microUSB to USB converter which would allow you to plug the USB gamepad directly into the phone.

Comment: An OTG cable will only work if the phone supports OTG, of course.